# flutter firestore geopoint are not shoing as markers

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to show markers on google map from firestore by retriving geopoint , but it is not showing the markers but showing only one at camera position. my code is given below. i can not find where did i made the mistake. the methods are not retriving any value from the firestore.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


 class heatmap extends StatefulWidget {
   @override

   _heatmapState createState() => _heatmapState();
 }

 class _heatmapState extends State<heatmap> {

var clients=[];
GoogleMapController mapController;
List<Marker> allMarkers=[];
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;


 Future<void> initState()  {

setState(() {
  clients=[];

  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('markers').get().then((docs)  {


    if(docs.docs.isNotEmpty){
      for(int i=0;i<docs.docs.length;i++){
        initMarker(docs.docs[i].data());
      }
    }



  });

});


 }


 initMarker(clients){

   allMarkers.add( Marker(

       markerId: MarkerId('my'),
     position: LatLng(clients['coords'].latitude,clients['coords'].longitude),
   )
   );


 }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new Scaffold(
       appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Red Flag areas',
           style: TextStyle(
             color: Colors.white,
             letterSpacing: 2.0,
             fontSize: 28.0,
           )),
         centerTitle: true,
         backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,


       ),
       body: GoogleMap(

         onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
                   initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                     target: LatLng(23.8103, 90.4125),
                     zoom: 11.0
                   ),
                   myLocationEnabled: true,


                   markers: Set.from(allMarkers),


                 )

           );


   }
   void onMapCreated(controller){
    setState(() {

      mapController=controller;
    });
   }
 }
```

[here is the data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0A9X.png)

Answer (score 0):

Move `setState` call in `initMarker()` method as follows:

```
initMarker(clients) {
    setState(() =>  allMarkers.add(Marker(...)) );
}
```